# How to custom cookie path from different link (local and server)

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, cookies

I have some trouble with setting up a correct Cookie path. What do i want to achieve?

1. I have a project that runs on my localhost server, with a path `http://localhost/project_folder/Controller/function`
2. I can set the Cookie path using the mentioned relative path `/project_folder/Controller/function` and it works
3. But when the project runs on another server, where the structure is a bit different, i.e.: `http://localhost/project` part is replaced by `http://www.example.com/Controller`, then the trouble begins

**I am using CodeIgniter framework.**

To achieve the metioned i have tried using the `base_url()` function CodeIgniter provides and if i change the site path in the configuration it works on the second server but does not work on the local one and vice-versa ...

How should i properly handle the Cookie path in this situation?

---

**EDITED:**

It's a simple Cookie set (i'm using a Custom cookie function in JavaScript and i'm setting the Cookie via JavaScript):

```
createCookie('filter_products', params, '1', '<?php echo base_url('Controller/function'); ?>');
```

The problem is, that the `base_url()` function returns the path below like i said before:

`http://localhost/project_folder/Controller/function`

But on the server the `localhost/project_folder/` part is replaced by the domain name, so how can i create the Cookie path dynamically?

Comment: Can you provide some code examples of what you've already tried? Put us more in the context.

Comment: i have updated my question please see it again, @CodiMech25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind is, that you should avoid setting Cookies via JavaScript if it is possible and use the CodeIgniter [built-in helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/cookie_helper.html) or the [native PHP functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.network.php).

To your question:

For dynamic decision on which server you are, you can use the PHP [super-global](https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server) `$_SERVER` value which is accessible from anywhere in your code. The `SERVER_NAME` field contains the actual name of the host, so you can use something like:

```
<?php

if (isset($_SERVER, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {
    if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] === 'localhost') {
        // set base path to localhost/project_folder
    } else {
        // set base path to www.example.com <- MORE SECURE
        // or, set base path to $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] <- INSECURE (any server could be written to the config)
    }
}
```